# Efficient scatterplot with specific colors for each point using Matplotlib

Tags: python, performance, matplotlib, plot, colors

I need to create a scatterplot in Python of N~10000 points where each point has a specific x, y, color and size. [This is what I am creating](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hQEdj.jpg). But the way I am doing it takes a very long time (~10 sec for 1000 points, ~2 min for 10000 points). This is a dummy code that represents what I am doing:

```
# x = [list of x coords]
# y = [list of y coords]
# colors = [list of color triples]
# sizes = [list of marker sizes]

f,ax = plt.figure()

N = 10000
for i in range(N):
    ax.plot(x[i],y[i], marker='.', color=colors[i], markersize = sizes[i])
```

Using plt.scatterplot takes the same amount of time. Is there a better (faster) way of achieving the same result?

Answer (score 0):

There is no `plt.scatterplot`. If you mean `plt.scatter` it will be much faster, because can call it only once instead of `N` times.

```
# x = [list of x coords]
# y = [list of y coords]
# colors = [list of color triples]
# sizes = [list of marker sizes]

f,ax = plt.subplots()

ax.scatter(x,y, marker='.', c=colors, s = sizes)
```